# How to create intentional audio feedback loops with level volume

Tags: volume, feedback

When creating intentional video feedback loops (by pointing a camera at a monitor), the camera automatically equalizes the brightness so that the screen is not all black or all white. This is what gives the loops their complexity, and make them interesting to look at.

I want to create audio feedback loops, but the real-time playback volume is either too low (the sounds fade to nothing after a few cycles) or too high (terrible screeching sounds).  To create audio loops, is there some software that allows recording and real-time playback **with the volume constantly adjusting** so it is always playing at a set decibel level?

Answer (score 1):

There's two types of feedback - stable and unstable. Unstable feedback is when you get a constantly increasing signal level which cannot be controlled. Stable is when you have control over the level of feedback going into the signal path and can generate a controlled and stable signal that includes a feedback path.

There are many delay/echo type plugins that give you a high degree of control over the amount of feedback that you are sending back into the programme chain. I would start with one of these.

The approach of simply amplifying a microphone and then placing the microphone next to the amplified sound source will only ever result in uncontrolled and unstable feedback loops. They won't be what you are looking for.

Use a delay initially to generate some signal artifacts and then use a feedback path to re-introduce the delayed signal back into the original signal path. You will have full control over the amount of signal returning to the signal path.

You can opt to use dynamics on the final output of the signal path - in fact you might find that you get some interesting effects from using some additional processing in the side-chain of the compressor.

Definitely limit the output using a separate limiter.

Answer (score 1):

I work with feedbacks as a creative tool every time. It's a powerful and very wide topic as it was said. There are some elements of the puzzle that needs to be tweaked VERY sensitive to achieve musical effects - instead of damage a speaker or an ear. I use a condenser microphone placed near the speaker - this needs some experiment. Too close means very fast/quick induction, huge feedback gain and no control. Too far means no feedback. I use a filter / eg to shape the harmonic content of the feedback sound - check NIIO Iotine Core 3 Self Oscillating Feedback Machine.

Answer (score 0):

First of,  there are 2 ways of creating feedback.

One is having a single repetition produced by a delay pedal and feeding the signal back to it.  This is the genuine feedback loop.

And the kinda pseudo feedback of some delay pedals.

Anyway,  i think you ve found your feedback anyway.

So to the real question, the only thing you need is a compressor.

If you use the first type of feedback(Aux Send) you'll need to use the compressor as an insert in the delay channel and check the pre-fader Send.

If you simple turn a feedback knob all the way up,  just compress afterwards -  in series.

Compression settings are somewhat irrelevant,  as feedback grows so much that 99% of the time the compressor will just stay down.

Afterwards you can safely increase or decrease the volume of the effect by using the Make Up gain of your compressor.

Thats all.